# Wordpress / WooCommerce Plugin Development

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to extend some WooCommerce functionality and my plugin will totally depend on WooCommerce (at the first lines I should check if woocommerce is activated).

So I am not sure should I develop Wordpress plugin or WooCommerce extension? Should I upload it to the WordPress Plugin repository or to WooCommerce Extension repository?

Respect to all.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/ - Check if WooCommerce is active & https://waclawjacek.com/check-wordpress-plugin-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your plugin in WP repository and rename it with "your plugin for woocommerce" and specified what version of woocommerce test for your code to description line.

Comment: In that case, will my plugin shows on Plugins page or WooCommerce->Extensions page?
Thank you for your comment

Comment: You can follow this topic from Woocommerce documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/